# Why would I use a document store instead of regular file storage?

Tags: mongodb, file, cassandra, nosql

I'm going to build a webservice in which I'm going to store a fairly large number of images and PDFs. For storing this I've got the option of storing the files as regular files and recording their file-names in a DB, along with their possible title, comments, etc. On the other hand I could also use a document store such as Cassandra or MongDB. Seeing that I have no experience in using a document store, I'm kind of unsure of why I would go for that option however.

As far as I understand, the advantage of a document store is mainly the scalability and replication possibilities, whereas the main advantage (for me at least) of using simple files is its simplicity.

Which other reasons would you say are detrimental for choosing one over the other? All tips are welcome!

Comment: If your unsure about the benefits then normally there are none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from your description a few things come to my mind:

> I'm going to store a fairly large number of images and PDFs.

Ok, let's assume every user is going to store some 10 MB, which actually is not much. Now let's assume you have 10000 users. This is a mere 100GB of data, no problem, you can store that easily in a file system (which comes with other drawbacks, but more on that later). Now let's assume your app is a hit, and your users multiply by 10. Now we have 1TB of data, and even on the biggest disks, we should start to find a way to scale, and for EBS, you have already reached the hard limit. Your options of scaling are either setting up a cluster file system, which isn't exactly easy to administer or do manual partitioning by using a network file system. Now what happens if one of these servers goes down? Automatic failover? Bad luck, you'd have to set up a High Availability solution yourself. Easy to set up redundancy? Bad luck, too. Integrating both? Not an easy task, and you really need to know what you are doing.

With MongoDB, scaling out is much easier (though it is not easy to do correctly). If you know what you are doing, a replicated sharded cluster can be set up fairly quickly. A sharded cluster is a storage distributed over one to hundreds or even thousands of nodes, which essentially means that reads and writes are distributed over the cluster and the cluster shares it's resources, making it possible to store PBs of data. Since it is very likely that one of the machines of the cluster fails when running hundreds or thousands of them, MongoDB comes with an automatic failover mechanism called replica sets. So a single shard consists of at least two data bearing nodes and when one of those fails, the other one takes over automatically.

Here is another advantage I see from storing the files in MongoDB: you have to access the database anyway, and I don't see the point of asking the database where a file might be, waiting for the database to respond and then access the file system (with all the necessary checks in case the access fails) to retrieve the file when I could have the file sent back to me from the database the first place.

Another, yet subtle problem of storing the metadata in a DB and the files in a file system is that it is much harder to maintain consistency between the metadata and the actual file. The data is stored in two unconnected systems, after all.

Here is what I'd do: If there is the slightest possibility that there will be files larger than 16MB (the limit of a BSON document in MongoDB), I'd use [MongoDB's GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) and store a reference to the respective owner(s) in the individual file's [metadata](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/gridfs/#the-files-collection). In some cases, it might be reasonable to store a reference to the file in the owner document, instead.

If there is not the slightest chance that an individual file will exceed the 16MB limit, you can use a standard MongoDB collection to store the files.

Some advice in case you decide to use MongoDB:

- If it is a commercial project, it is wise to hire a MongoDB DBA at least for some time. While MongoDB seems to be extremely easy, there are some caveats to be dealt with. Since these usually depend on the individual situation, I can't give too much general advice here.
- Plan your scaling strategy *early*. I'd suggest starting with a sharded cluster with a single shard if there is the slightest chance that you will break the limits of your hardware.
- ***Always*** have the individual shards consisting of a replica set with *at least* 2 data bearing nodes and an [arbiter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-arbiter/). (As a rule of thumb: More data bearing nodes is better.) Otherwise you don't have automatic failover and maintaining the cluster will *always* result in downtime or data being unavailable. Depending on your write concern setting, data may even be silently lost during write operations in case your shard don't consist of a replica set and the target shard is down. Again: ***Always have the shards of a cluster consist of a replica set!***

Comment: That is one awesome answer! Thanks for the clarity. I'm definitely going to use a document store then. Just have to make my decision between MongoDB and Cassandra. From what I understand MongoDB is easier to setup, while Cassandra is faster when scaled out (http://planetcassandra.org/nosql-performance-benchmarks/). Next to MongoDB, do you also have experience with Cassandra?

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer, then. ;) I do not have experience with Cassandra. From a quick overlook, there were major mistakes made in the test setup of the first test regarding the mongodb setup, choosing the default Id field unhashed as a shard key is a performance killer because what happens in this case is that all write operations will go to one shard and the rest of the cluster will only receive chunks migrated from that shard, resulting in poor read and write performance. I will dig deeper into that, but from my point of view, I wouldn't trust at least the first comparison too much.

Comment: Plus, the test is kind of old, running against mongodb 2.2.2, which is outdated by now. Major performance improvements were made in 2.4 and especially 2.6. In one of the versions, the whole storage engine was rewritten (can't remember which one), and the query engine was rewritten as of version 2.6.